# CentOS 7 postpone updates in Spacewalk 2.6

Tags: centos, deployment, spacewalk

I use Spacewalk 2.6 for deploy and central configuration my CentOS 7 systems.

In default state are updates provided automatically on all clients.

How do I configure Spacewalk not to distribute updates automatically but manually after approval?

Comment: My knowledge is mainly from when I used RedHat Satellite so I won't post an answer, but there you created a "release" i.e. *"our-rhel7-2018-02"* by [cloning the upstream channel](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_network_satellite/5.0/html/channel_management_guide/channel_management_guide-custom_channel_and_package_management-cloning_software_channels) and that cloned channel would  only get updated with specific Errata (or completely frozen and for updates a new channel would be cloned to make a "new release" ) and hosts would be subscribed to that channel

Answer (score 0):

Solution is not so difficult:

1) I had to clone channels with its child subchannels. This I was not able to do in web app but in console. 
On Spacewalk machine should be installed package `spacecmd`

Clonning itself is done by command:

```
softwarechannel_clonetree -s centos_7_x86_64_package_channel -p "testing-"
```

I have created 2 clones of channels

```
softwarechannel_clonetree -s centos_7_x86_64_package_channel -p "production-"
```

2) syncing packages can not be done also in web interface and can be done only by cli

```
softwarechannel_sync centos_7_x86_64_package_channel testing-centos_7_x86_64_package_channel -q
softwarechannel_sync centos_7_x86_64_package_channel_centosplus testing-centos_7_x86_64_package_channel_centosplus -q
softwarechannel_sync centos_7_x86_64_package_channel_elrepo testing-centos_7_x86_64_package_channel_elrepo -q
softwarechannel_sync centos_7_x86_64_package_channel_epel testing-centos_7_x86_64_package_channel_epel -q
softwarechannel_sync centos_7_x86_64_package_channel_extras testing-centos_7_x86_64_package_channel_extras -q
softwarechannel_sync centos_7_x86_64_package_channel_spacewalk testing-centos_7_x86_64_package_channel_spacewalk -q
softwarechannel_sync centos_7_x86_64_package_channel_updates testing-centos_7_x86_64_package_channel_updates -q
#sync errata
softwarechannel_errata_sync centos_7_x86_64_package_channel testing-centos_7_x86_64_package_channel
softwarechannel_errata_sync centos_7_x86_64_package_channel_epel testing-centos_7_x86_64_package_channel_epel
```

The same can be done with production channel